# How can I get smooth random movement (2D Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, rigid-bodies

I'm using Random.onUnitSphere to simulate bubbles floating around jostling for position. It works well although the movement is too "jerky". I'd like to create the same effect but slow it down and make smoother random movements. Is there anyway I can easily achieve this? Here's my code:

```
private void Update()
{
     if (floaty == true)
     {
         rb.AddRelativeForce(Random.onUnitSphere * speed);
         speed = 0.06f;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perlin noise random walker should work

```
//There are probably better ways to do this.
Vector3 RandomSmoothPointOnUnitSphere(float time)
{
  
  //Get the x of the vector
  float x = Math.PerlinNoise(time, /* your x seed */);
  
  //Get the y of the vector
  float y = Math.PerlinNoise(time, /* your y seed */);
  
  //Get the z of the vector
  float z = Math.PerlinNoise(time, /* your z seed */);
  
  //Create a vector3
  Vector3 vector = new Vector3(x, y, z);
  
  //Normalize the vector and return it
  return Vector3.Normalize(vector);
  
}
```

And in the Update function

```
if (floaty)
{
  
  //Get the vector
  Vector3 movementvector = RandomSmoothPointOnUnitSphere(Time.time);
  
  //You can also use CharacterController.Move()
  transform.Translate(movementvector * Time.deltatime);
  
}
```

I should also mention that this approach shouldn't work with RigidBody.ApplyForce(), but I don't usually use Unity's default physics, so it may. Regardless, it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I can't really seem to get the Perlin method to work here for what I'm trying to achieve. I appreciate the idea though, it was something I hadn't thought of and led me down a path of more discovery of what the Perlin method can do (mainly with procedurally generated terains etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I have to ask what effect are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to make 2D sprite bubbles float smoothly in place randomly on the y and x axis. rb.AddRelativeForce(Random.onUnitSphere * speed); achieves this but with frenetic shaky movements.

Comment: Maybe a 2d walker? If you want particles, I'd recon using unity's particle system. I think it should be just a matter of setting the y to 0 in the walker function to get a 2d walker from the 3d one. `Vector3 vector = new Vector3(x, 0, z);`

Comment: Do you need bubbles that actually push other objects around? Because otherwise the particle system would be a good thing to use - I use it myself for bubbles. It has a built in "noise" feature which can create neat, random movement.